# How to click a button in selenium with java without name or ID

Tags: java, selenium, web, driver

How can i use selenium to click this button?

```
 <button type="submit" class="button--primary button button--icon button--icon--login"><span class="button-text">Log in</span></button>
```

I have tried these

```
    driver.findElement(By.className("button--primary button button--icon button--icon--login")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class='button--primary button button--icon button--icon--login')]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/button[text()='Log in' and @class='button']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span/button[text()='Log in'][1]")).click();
```

but no avail, help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looks like you almost had it with your last try.

This should work though:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button//span[text()='Log in']")).click();
```

When you use contains you should have a comma not an equals after the @class. Your own path would've worked in that case:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'button--primary button button--icon button--icon--login')]")).click();
```

Comment: Ahh thanks so much! it's always a silly thing which stops my code from working lol

Comment: @Scrub No problem. I do these things regularly enough to spot them :)

Comment: @Scrub you should post another question with the code you have tried and the html element you are trying to target. Explanation and visibility is hindered in the comments section